# pip install fails inside conda environment but works in base

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

(Running Windows 10 Home)

Steps to reproduce problem:

- Install miniconda
- Install MS Visual Studio 2017 C++ build tools with Windows 8.1 and 10 SDK
- `conda create -n myenv python=3.5`
- `activate myenv`
- `pip install spectrum`

Fails with error

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual 
C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

- `deactivate`
- `pip install spectrum`

Build succeeds. What's going on?

Comment: Open "Developer Command Line Prompt for VS2017" and do `pip install spectrum` from there.

Comment: I want to understand why installation fails specifically inside an environment. I can already build the package outside of an environment.

Comment: have you examined the system paths by running `set` from within windows cmd? Eventually conda is messing up one of them when being activated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I was at this for 6 hours today. All the following failed:

```
Firewall reset on Windows 10
conda update
miniconda reinstall
distribution upgrade (Debian)
pip downgrade/upgrade
pip installed from pypi using get-pip.py
```

none of which made the problem go away, however, other conda environments were working for me as were new ones.

Turns out that if you wipe out a conda environment and then install a new one with a name you used before the cache can be mangled. So the fix is:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.cache
```

in a linux environment at least.